# Connect two containers between them failed

Tags: bash, docker, shell, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have some issue when I try to manage docker-compose and dockerfile together.
I researched and I know that is possible to use docker-compose without a dockerfile, but I think for me is better to use Dockerfile too because I want an environment to be easy to be modified.
The problem is that I want to have a container with postgres, which is a dependent component to another container, container named api which is used to run the application.
This container contains Java 17 and Maven 3 and take using docker-compose, image from Dockerfile. The problem is: while I use Dockerfile, everything is fine, but actually when I use docker-compose, I got this error:
`2021-12-08T08:36:37.221247254Z /usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh: line 50: exec: mvn test: not found`

Configuration files are:

- Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.8.4
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"
ARG SHA=a9b2d825eacf2e771ed5d6b0e01398589ac1bfa4171f36154d1b5787879605507802f699da6f7cfc80732a5282fd31b28e4cd6052338cbef0fa1358b48a5e3c8
ARG BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
      curl procps \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
  && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
  && echo "${SHA}  /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
  && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  && rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

COPY mvn-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh
COPY settings-docker.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/

COPY . .

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["mvn", "test"]
```

And docker-compose file:

```
services:
  api_service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    container_name: api_core_backend
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db

  postgres_db:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    container_name: postgres_core_backend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
```

Can anyone explain me why I got errors when I execute with docker-compose but everything is fine if I use dockerfile instead?
thank you.

Update: Link error while I try to connect to another container:

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Unable to obtain connection from database: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 08001
Error Code : 0
Message    : Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Comment: Debugging details should be included in the question itself, not as a link to an external resource. For one thing, we expect the question to be useful for future visitors, too; are you committing to keeping the link up for many years to come?

Comment: I don't think this link expires. But sure, I'll edit now.

Comment: For the error at line 50 of `mvn-entrypoint.sh`...what's in that script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The issue

Based on [the logs](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/iqiwopabez.sql), it looks like the issue is that you're using `localhost` as the hostname when you connect.

Docker compose creates an internal network where the hostnames are mapped to the service names. So in your case, the hostname is `postgres_db`.

Please see the [docker compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for more information.

### Solution

Try specifying `postgres_db` as the hostname :)